# How to observe change in a global Set variable in useEffect inside react component function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a page wherein there are Listings.
A user can check items from this list.

Whenever the user checks something it gets added to a **globally declared *Set***(each item's unique ID is added into this set). The ID's in this set need to be accessed by a seperate Component(lets call it `PROCESS_COMPONENT`) which processes the particular Listings whose ID's are present in the set.

My Listings code roughly looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { CheckBox, PROCESS_COMPONENT } from "./Process.jsx";

const ListItem = ({lItem}) => {
    return (
            <>
               //name,image,info,etc.
               <CheckBox lId={lItem.id}/>
            </>
)
};

function Listings() {
 // some declarations blah blah..
 return (
       <>
          <PROCESS_COMPONENT /> // Its a sticky window that shows up on top of the Listings.
          //..some divs and headings
          dataArray.map(item => { return <ListItem lItem={item} /> }) // Generates the list also containing the checkboxes
       </>
)
}
```

And the `Checkbox` and the `PROCESS_COMPONENT` functionality is present in a seperate file(`Process.jsx`).

It looks roughly like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let ProcessSet = new Set(); // The globally declared set.

const CheckBox = ({lID}) => {
   const [isTicked, setTicked] = useState(false);
   const onTick = () => setTicked(!isTicked);
   useEffect( () => {
     if(isTicked) {
          ProcessSet.add(lID);
     }
     else { 
          ProcessSet.delete(lID); 
     }
     console.log(ProcessSet); // Checking for changes in set.
   }, [isTicked]);
   return (
      <div onClick={onTick}>
       //some content
      </div>
   )
}

const PROCESS_COMPONENT = () => {
   const [len, setLen] = useState(ProcessSet.size);
   useEffect( () => {
      setLen(ProcessSet.size);
   }, [ProcessSet]); // This change is never being picked up.
   return (
        <div>
        <h6> {len} items checked </h6>
        </div>
   )
}

export { CheckBox, PROCESS_COMPONENT };
```

The Set itself does get the correct ID values from the `Checkbox`. But the `PROCESS_COMPONENT` does not seem to be picking up the changes in the Set and `len` shows 0(initial size of the set).

I am pretty new to react. However any help is appreciated.

### Edit:

Based on [@jdkramhoft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69910347/14770761)
's answer I made the set into a state variable in `Listings` function.

```
const ListItem = ({lItem,set,setPSet}) => {
   //...
        <CheckBox lID={lItem.id} pset={set} setPSet={setPSet} />
   )
}

function Listings() {
  const [processSet, setPSet] = useState(new Set());
  //....
      <PROCESS_COMPONENT set={processSet} />
      dataArray.map(item => { 
          return <ListItem lItem={item} set={processSet} setPSet={setPSet} /> 
      })
}
```

And corresponding changes in `Process.jsx`

```
const CheckBox = ({lID,pset,setPSet}) => {
  //...
  if (isTicked) {
     setPSet(pset.add(lID)); 
  }
  else {
     setPSet(pset.delete(lID));
  }
  //...
}

const PROCESS_COMPONENT = ({set}) => {
   //...
   setLen(set.size);
   //...
}
```

Now whenever I click the check box I get an error:

```
TypeError: pset.add is not a function. (In 'pset.add(lID)', 'pset.add' is undefined)
```

Similar error occurs for the delete function as well.

Comment: If you want changes to the Set to be reactive simply store it as a state variable at the appropriate parent level, or within a context which can be subscribed to by those components that need it.

Comment: @pilchard Okay. But where exaclty do I move the set to? Even in the Listings file there are two function components that need access to it. And declaring it globally in Listings and passing it as a prop to both `CheckBox` and `PROCESS_COMPONENT` also seems to yield the exact same problem.

Comment: @pilchard nvm. Found the appropriate parent. It is the `Listings` function. Silly ol me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the set should be a react state `const [mySet, setMySet] = useState(new Set());` if you want react to properly re-render with detected changes. If you need the set to be available to multiple components you can pass it to them with props or use a context.

Secondly, React checks if dependencies like `[ProcessSet]` has been changed with something like `===`. Even though the items in the set are different, no change is detected because the object is the same and there is no re-render.

**Update:**

The `setState` portion of `[state, setState] = useState([]);` is not intended to mutate the previous state - only to provide the next state. So to update your set you would do something like:

```
  const [set, setSet] = useState(new Set())
  const itemToAdd = ' ', itemToRemove = ' ';
  setSet(prev => new Set([...prev, itemToAdd]));
  setSet(prev => new Set([...prev].filter(item => item !== itemToRemove)));
```

As you might notice, this makes adding and removing from a set as slow as a list. So unless you need to make a lot of checks with `set.has()` I'd recommend using a list:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])
  const itemToAdd = ' ', itemToRemove = ' ';
  setItems(prev => [...prev, itemToAdd]);
  setItems(prev => prev.filter(item => item !== itemToRemove));
```

Comment: Okay. So I did this. Created a useState variable in the `Listings` function. Passed the variable and the setter as props to `CheckBox` and `PROCESS_COMPONENT`. But now the `Set.add` and `Set.delete` within the `CheckBox` component seems to fail and throw an **undefined** error.

Comment: Updated this in the question.

Comment: Yes, you can’t simply `add` anymore as this will mutate state. You’ll need to pass a callback to setState clone the set and then add.

Comment: @pilchard How exactly am I supposed to do it? I tried cloning the set within `useEffect` of `CheckBox` by doing a `let pset_clone = new Set(pset);` and then pass that into `setPSet()` but still no avail. It just drops a `TypeError: Type Error`.

Comment: I’m on mobile at the moment, but can type it up later.

Comment: @jdkramhoft Okay. So I cannot edit the previous state with setState. I did not know that. So here I am supposed to just make a brand new set everytime I click a checkbox. That sounds inefficient. However this seems to have solved the problem while also giving proper explanation. Also is List faster than Set? I wont be using any `set.has()`, just looping through it. I just picked it earlier to prevent duplication, but that doesn't seem to be a problem because of the checkbox system.